# julia decisiontree model - get features list

Tags: julia, decision-tree

I had created a DecisionTree model in Julia using some features that I had created through an algorithm.

```
model_rest2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(n_subfeatures=0)
@time DecisionTree.fit!(model_rest2, convert(Matrix, df3[:,[16:45;49:50;52:81;83:end]]), df3[:,:type_1])
```

I seem to have modified the feature building steps due to which while testing the model now it is not running as the number of features in the model is different from the number of features available in the test set. Is there a way to find the list of features being used by the model so that I can add the missing features?

Comment: Which package are you using? DecisionTree?
Are you sure you haven't just transposed one matrix or something?

Comment: Yes I am using DecisionTree package. As I am using numeric column index so I think I have made some changes in the algo due to which the column indexes have shifted. But can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't get any answers, I changed my modus Operandi and entered all the column names instead of the numeric column range. This ensured I dont get into this issue again.